# Django & Geraldo Reports error pdf not displayed correctly

Tags: django, pdf, reporting-services, geraldo

I'm using Django 1.6.1 and Geraldo Reports 0.4.17, Firexos 24.3.0.  Both in DEV & production environments I get the error "This PDF document might not be displayed correctly.  In production,using Nginx 1.0.15 and gunicorn 18.0.  Only browser used is Firefox.

If I run 2-3 reports or run one, then go any page and then run another report or even same as before, error comes up.  If I restart Nginx & gunicorn, any report shows up perfect, until error again.

Checked for errors on nginx access & error logs, guninconr & django logs and there is no error reported to this issue.

When calling the reports I was originally using the standard 'generate_by method' and then when seeing this report in DEV env, changed it to 'generate_under_process_by' method.  Unfortunately, that does not help.

How can I troubleshoot / solve this issue?  Is there something I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was using the same HTTP response variable for all reports.  I must define its value inside each report, even if it's repetitive.